# how to copy the required Items of NSMutableArray to NSArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have `NSMutableArray` of Results it has 6 items. I want to copy the first three contents
to another `NSArray`.

Comment: did you tried anything ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `subarrayWithRange:`:

```
NSMutableArray *oldArray = ... // the mutable array with the 6 objects
NSArray *result = [oldArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(3, oldArray.count))];
```

Comment: wow nice one... never thought of this :)

Comment: it is giving exception

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: Did you include the same check I have using `MIN(3, oldArray.count)`? This ensures the code will work even if `oldArray` has less than 3 objects in it. The error indicates that your array is empty.

Comment: and if i want array items from 3 to 6 then how can i write please

Comment: Just update the values you pass to `NSMakeRange`. But you may need to do more validation of the array count. If you want objects 3 to 6 then make sure the array has at least 6 objects in it first. Just remember that the second argument to `NSMakeRange` is the length, not the end index.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutalbeArray *newArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i < results.count; i++){
    [newArray addObject:results[i]];
    if(i == 2)
       break;
}
```

Comment: it gives this exception -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: It means you have only one object

Comment: i have added my more code of array which is with six items in it check that

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple loop:

```
NSMutableArray *resultantArray=[NSMutableArray new];
for(NSInteger i=0;i<3;i++){
    [resultantArray addObject:firstArray[i]];
}
```

Comment: @scott: Thanks for that typo correction :)

Comment: it is shows incampitibel type of array arguement addObejct 1

Comment: to make you more clear

Comment: Your `firstArray` or the array from where you are fetching data does not contain 6 objects, i would say it contain less than 3!!! Or check before using this code. check for [arry count]

Comment: it shows 6 sir in NSLog

Comment: ObjectData *theCellData = [resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: this is how access items of the arrays like theCellData.category etc